# How to find extra newlines with RubyMine?

Tags: rubymine

I am trying to detect extra newlines between two methods in my code.
How can I detect all of them with RubyMine? For example:

```
def some_method
end


# two new lines
def other_method
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Edit -> Find -> Find in Path
- Set "Text to find" to

  ```
  end\n\n\n
  ```
- Check "Regular expression"
- click Find

There might be spaces before any of those newlines, so you might find more matches with

```
end *\n *\n *\n
```

You could also consider removing extra newlines automatically by reformatting your code:

- make sure that Preferences -> Project settings -> Code Style -> Ruby -> Other -> "Blank lines around methods" is set the way you want (and all the other Ruby code style settings are the way you want)
- in the project page, select the parent directory of all of the files you want to reformat
- Code -> Reformat Code...
- hit Run

Of course you would only do this if you were prepared to reformat everything.